# AWS Ec2 Ubuntu Instance Running Angular 14 App

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, execute

I am using Angular-14 deploying in AWS EC2 instance
I can run app using following command

```
ng serve  --port 4202 --host 0.0.0.0 --public-host ec2-X-XXX-XXX-XXX.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com nohup
```

And I can able to access the web link over internet, no problem.

But when I turn of putty shell, and then try to access it is no more accessible.

May be this is duplicate topic, since I search for lot of similar query on stackoverflow unfortunately dint match what I am expecting.

My thought is with `nohup` attribute it should allow me to execute the APP in the background and keep it alive till I wanted.

Please give me some knowledge to improve myself to use EC2 efficiently.
Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Well, so did you try `nohup` or not?

Comment: Yes it is mentioned in the command in top

Comment: My concern is even though with `nohup` it is not allowing me to leave the shell, I have to do `Ctrl + C` to come out, and eventually it is breaking execution

Comment: @Marcin it was my bad I was skipping `&` in the end, thanks for pushing me to bring best.

Answer (score 0):

Actual the correct command worked for me as below:

```
nohup ng serve --port 4202 --host 0.0.0.0 --public-host ec2-X-XXX-XXX-XXX.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com > nglog.out &
```